# LDAP Client in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to authenticate an GAE app using LDAP protocol - through client?

The JNDI package is blacklisted in java runtime of GAE. Is there any other alternate for this?

Any pointer would be must appreciated?

Comment: this may help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319176/need-to-call-ldap-in-app-engines-python-environment

Comment: Thanks for you help, I just want to create a LDAP Server in Google App Engine, currently it is not possible and we have started using Google Compute Engine.